# GO storing data returns EOF

Tags: go, eof, go-gin

I'm new to golang and I'm trying to build rest api, So far GET endpoints are working for me fine, but I'm having difficulties with POST method(creating user):

That's how my User struct is looking:

```
type User struct {
    ID        uint32    `gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment" json:"id"`
    Name      string    `json:"name" binding:"required"`
    Email     string    `json:"email" binding:"required"`
    Password  string    `json:"password" binding:"required"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"updated_at"`
}
```

Repo method for storing users:

```
func CreateUser() (*models.User, error) {

    var input models.User

    user := models.User{Name: input.Name, Email: input.Email, Password: input.Password}

    result := Config.DB.Debug().Create(&user)
    if result.Error != nil {
        msg := result.Error
        return nil, msg
    }
    return &user, nil
}
```

And called from controller:

```
func CreateUser(c *gin.Context) {

    //var user models.User
    user := models.User{}
    user.Prepare()

    var input models.User

    err := c.BindJSON(&input)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "Error": err.Error(), //this error is thrown
        })
        return
    }

    userData, err := repo.CreateUser()

    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": err,
        })
        return

    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "data": userData,
    })
}
```

I'm using gorm to interact with database and if I'm hardcoding the inputs e.g.

```
 User{Name: "Jinzhu", Email: "test@mail.com", Password: "pass1234"}
```

Then the data is stored, but if these are passed as parameters via postman, then I'm getting this error:

**`{"Error":"EOF"}`**

Been bashing my head for several hours now and still don't understand where's the error.

Comment: If `c.BindJSON` is returning EOF then that means that the body of the request is empty. You need to send a body with the request.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks, but could you please be more specific like what kind of GO methods etc. to use?

Comment: Well if you ain't gonna send a body in the HTTP request then there is no JSON to bind and you should NOT use `c.BindJSON` at all. But, given what the handler function seems to be trying to implement, you should simply include a JSON body in the HTTP request and that should fix at least the EOF error.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks for your help, I have solved my issue. Please make an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As mkopriva pointed

`c.BindJSON` is returning `EOF` which means nothing is being sent in request

To solve this you need `json` in request body which would look something like:

```
{name: "Jinzhu", email: "test@mail.com", password: "pass1234"}
```

Example `curl` request:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{name: "Jinzhu", email: "test@mail.com", password: "pass1234"}'
```